ASP.NET REST API is working locally but giving error when uploaded to a web server
I have an old rest API which is working fine in Visual Studio 2019 with SQL Server. But the same API, when uploaded to a web server, is not working. I get the following error.

The resource cannot be found.

My web config looks like this:
Note: Service is running but no method is accessible.
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" 
             connectionString="Data Source=secureserver.net;Integrated Security=False;Initial Catalog=myDB;User ID=username;Password=password" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
                     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
                     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
                     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
                     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
                     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
                     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                     passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
                     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
                     applicationName="/" 
                     type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
                     applicationName="/"  
                     type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="serviceBehaviors">
                  <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                  <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
              </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
              <behavior name="web" >
                  <webHttp></webHttp>
              </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
              <binding name="largeMessage" 
                       maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                       maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                       closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" 
                       receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
                   <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
                   <security mode="None"/>
               </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      
    <service name="ExamService.ExamService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviors">
      <endpoint address="" contract="ExamService.IExamService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessage" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"  />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
      To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
      Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>



Since it is working locally, have you tried installing the deployed code on local IIS server? Try installing on your local IIS and if it works properly, use the same deploy code on the web server. I have added a useful link for you
ASP.NET Deployment Documentation
